# How to proxy tile sources with reversed Y axis TMS source

Tags: tiles, mapproxy

I have the following URL https://htonl.dev.openstreetmap.org/ngi-tiles/tiles/50k/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png which I am trying to cache using mapproxy. I have the following config

```
sources:
ngi_tiles:
    type: tile
    grid: osm_grid
    url: https://htonl.dev.openstreetmap.org/ngi-tiles/tiles/50k/%(z)s/%(x)s/%(-y)s.png

grids:
   webmercator:
      base: GLOBAL_WEBMERCATOR
   osm_grid:
     base: GLOBAL_MERCATOR
     srs: 'EPSG:3857'
     tile_size: [512, 512]
     origin: nw
```

The format of the ULR seems to generate an error with mapproxy

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mapproxy/client/tile.py", line 81, in substitute
    return self.template % data
KeyError: '-y'
```

I have tried without the inverted y-axis but changing the origin of the grid from `nw` to other supported formats but it still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you remove the - from %(-y) and change the origin to sw you'll probably achieve what you need:

```
sources:
ngi_tiles:
    type: tile
    grid: osm_grid
    url: https://htonl.dev.openstreetmap.org/ngi-tiles/tiles/50k/%(z)s/%(x)s/%(y)s.png

grids:
   webmercator:
      base: GLOBAL_WEBMERCATOR
   osm_grid:
     base: GLOBAL_MERCATOR
     srs: 'EPSG:3857'
     tile_size: [512, 512]
     origin: sw
```